# Animation Template Method for Snake Game

Tags: javascript, animation, ecmascript-6, lodash.js, snake-game

I have recently finished my first iteration of a template method implementation for a JavaScript canvas animation of the snake game. However, I would love for the community to critique this code and inform me where I am going wrong?

In my opinion, a bad smell for me is the number of times `this` is used throughout. Furthermore, the number of properties in the `SnakeAnimator` implementation (Note: These properties are passed upon extension).

```
const VectorFactory = require("./model/vector");
const _ = require("lodash");
const Animator = require('./animators/animator');

let SnakeAnimator = {
    vectors: [],
    canvas: null,
    xAdd: null,
    canvas_context: null,
    canvas_height: 0,
    canvas_width: 0,

    initialise: function (options) {
        this.canvas_context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.canvas_width = this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas_height = this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.canvas_context.strokeStyle = options.colour;
    },

    draw: function () {
        this.canvas_context.beginPath();

        for( let i = 0; i < this.vectors.length; i++) {
            this.canvas_context.moveTo(this.vectors[i][0].x, this.vectors[i][0].y);
            this.canvas_context.lineTo(this.vectors[i][1].x, this.vectors[i][1].y);
        }

        this.canvas_context.stroke();
        this.canvas_context.closePath();
    },

    update: function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.vectors.length; i++) {
            this.vectors[i][0].x = this.vectors[i][0].x + this.xAdd;
            this.vectors[i][1].x = this.vectors[i][1].x + this.xAdd;
        }
    },

    clear: function() {
        this.canvas_context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas_width, this.canvas_height);
    },

    addSnake: function() {
        this.vectors.push([VectorFactory(0, this.canvas_height / 2), VectorFactory(this.xAdd, this.canvas_height / 2)]);
    }
};
_.extend(SnakeAnimator, Animator);

module.exports = SnakeAnimator;
```

The template method implementation is as follows:

```
let Animator = {
    animate: function() {
        this.update();
        this.clear();
        this.draw();
    }
};

module.exports = Animator;
```

I would greatly appreciate any feedback on how I can improve this / my overall knowledge of JavaScript applications should be structured as I have struggled with this for a while.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good question, I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const VectorFactory = require("./model/vector");
const _ = require("lodash");
const Animator = require('./animators/animator');
```

Consider using ES6 and imports. That way, your code will be a bit more future-proof. The caveat is that you need to have a build system and a transpiler. Since you have `require`, I suppose you do have a build system in place. You just need the transpiler.

Now I suppose you use the code this way:

```
const SnakeAnimator = require('./animators/snake-animator');

const snakeAnimatorInstance = _.extend(SnakeAnimator);

snakeAnimatorInstance.canvas = referenceToCanvas

snakeAnimatorInstance.initialise();

gameLoop(snakeAnimatorInstance.animate);
```

Looks ok, but it would be nice to automate much of the setup using a factory function that accepts params, and pops it in to a composed object.

```
const SnakeAnimator = require('./animators/snake-animator');

snakeAnimatorInstance = SnakeAnimator.createInstance({
  canvas: referenceToCanvas,
  // other options for initialization
});

gameLoop(snakeAnimatorInstance.animate);
```

Now for the properties

```
vectors: [],
canvas: null,
xAdd: null,
canvas_context: null,
canvas_height: 0,
canvas_width: 0,
```

Looks like the only public property is `canvas`. All the others appear to be only used by internal functions like `initialize`. It would be nice to indicate that they shouldn't be modified directly. By convention, a `_` is prefixed to the name.

Also, JS follows the camelCase convention in naming (notice `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`). Suggesting you follow for consistency.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, all the points are valid and I'll implement them. I'll keep them in mind for the future :)